# --load-extension parameter for chrome doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

Does anyone know how to load unpacked google chrome plugin from command line?
I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
"C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --load-extension="<path/to/unpacked/extension>"
```

The above command just opens a chrome browser window and doesn't load my extension.

Comment: Did you verify that it is loaded and just not enabled? <-- Guess, I've never "loaded" an extension in Chrome this way.

Comment: what's wrong with loading unpacked extensions in developer mode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most of the command-line flags are only effective when **all** existing instances of Chrome that corresponds to the chrome profile have been terminated.

If you don't see any Chrome window, open the task manager and kill every process called chrome.exe. After doing that, you can use `--load-extension=...` to temporarily load a Chrome extension (the extension will be gone when you start Chrome without this flag, again only after closing all running instances of Chrome).

Comment: Thanks! I noticed I did have some existing instances of chrome running. It works after killing all the instances of chrome.

Comment: How do we make that installation permanent instead of temporary?

Comment: How do we load more than one extension?

Comment: @zero_cool Separate them with commas. I'm loading react-dev-tools and redux-dev-tools in a NW.js manifest like this: ` --load-extension='./chrome_extensions/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd/2.17.0_0,./chrome_extensions/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/3.6.0_0'`

Comment: @TetraDev Did find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

U can load your extension without closing other Chrome instances. To do so in addition to `--load-extension` u have to specify User Data directory flag that differs from your current (that used by already running instances). But in new Chrome instance u will lose all ur User Data things (like history, other extensions, etc).

On Windows default User Data directory is `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`.

Example ("Target" field in Chrome's shortcut):

`"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --load-extension="C:\my-extension" --user-data-dir="C:\my-new-user-data"`